# How to automatically run my script on logon screen

Tags: batch-file

I want to know how I can automatically run my script on the logon screen when a user clicks on the change password button or when the password expired screen pops up and clicks on the ok button.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but afaik there is no way to achieve this. There is simply no mechanism to catch this event itself. You could schedule a task to check for expiring passwords every x minutes but I guess this is not what you are looking for.

However, if your are working with Microsoft Server 2008 or greater with Active Directory, there is a workaround I've found on Microsoft Technet: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9289ae59-2230-4d0d-8686-6e89457b8ad0/how-to-run-a-script-after-user-change-password-of-windows-account-windows-server-family?forum=winservergen

Comment: No problem you were a big help unlike some people who think they are better then you just because you don't know something and they do :)